# Should we use <kbd> in Markdown to indicate normal mode / insert mode keystrokes?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, formatting

To indicate in questions and answers that keystrokes are being typed in normal mode or insert mode, should `<kbd>` be the convention?

Or should we use backticks?

Also, should we lead off ex commands to by typed in normal mode with the colon? `:%!uniq` or `%!uniq`? Or <kbd>:</kbd>`%!uniq` (hopefully not).

Comment: It is up to the personal preference and taste of the user writing the post. I don't think there is a single "best way".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker you should add that as an answer. (Not that I agree with it, but it's definitely an answer to this question.)

Answer (score 7):

It is up to the personal preference and taste of the user writing the post. I don't think there is a single "best way". As long as the post is reasonably readable I would consider it to be fine.

One obvious downside of `<kbd>` is that it's awkward to type; so *especially* in long posts or posts with lots of examples backticks would be better (as in, lots easier to write).

Comment: Another obvious downside is that it's extremely ugly. (Counts as "personal preference" tho.)

Answer (score 5):

- To indicate keystrokes such as <kbd>/</kbd>, `<kbd>` is clear and natural

  - In case of longer sequences such as `V}x}}p` where typing out `<kbd>` for each character would be inconvenient, backticks are acceptable
- For Ex commands to be typed in normal mode, a leading colon as in `:%!uniq` is clear and natural

  - Using backticks to format these commands is clear and natural

Answer (score 3):

I think we should let the authors of the posts do what they feel is most readable, and make edits to improve clarity if necessary.

Trying to establish a convention for "this sort of markup means insert mode, that sort of markup means normal mode," seems like a lost cause. It will be difficult/tedious to enforce, and it won't be terribly obvious to new users coming across the site.

Answer (score 3):

As a supporter of semantics, I don't mind sticking my neck out there: I think `<kbd>` should be used. `<code>` (backtics) is for code, `<kbd>` is for specifically for user input. As such, I think any typed commands should use `<kbd>`.

However, an issue is that `<kbd>` is sort of a "hidden feature". I don't think it's worth making edits just to make the swap, but I'd like to see it as the site preference.

Comment: You mean like [<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> (image linked)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2WAOM.png)? You really _do_ like that more than `V}x}}p`?

Comment: @yo' `<kbd>Shift + V } x } } p </kbd>` is acceptable, and [W3C approved](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20812/discussion-between-yo-and-johnb).

Comment: Semantics shemantics. Are all these fancy semantics theories actually used anywhere (ie. by user agents), except for visual representation?