# <KBD> combo normalization

Tags: discussion

Should we enforce, by edit when we see it, a normalized `<kbd>`-combo norm?

Examples of how it is used are:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
3. <kbd>Alt+v</kbd>
4. <kbd>Alt + v</kbd>
5. <kbd>Alt + V</kbd>
6. …

Of those I favor number five, four being second. Assuming it is clear one do not mean <kbd>Alt + Shift + V</kbd> (by the capital letter.) Is lower case better?

A *stand alone* combo can work in a question / answer with separate `<kbd>`'s – but when one get several in short proximity I find it quickly to become somewhat messy – and it is a [PITA](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/107/220) both to write (and read?).

What ya think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we use <kbd> in Markdown to indicate normal mode / insert mode keystrokes?](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-use-kbd-in-markdown-to-indicate-normal-mode-insert-mode-keystrokes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the examples (except maybe the first one) are clear and unambiguous (assuming you mean `Alt` + `v` at the same time). And as long as this is the case, I see no need to go around editing other people's posts.

The first one may mean either *"press `Alt` then `v`"*, or *"Press and hold `Alt`, and then press `v` while holding `Alt`"*. So this *may* be a candidate for editing if the answer doesn't have enough context, if it's mixed with other notations in the same answer, or is unclear for some other reason.

Some people may not even use the `<kbd>` tags in the first place, but rather use the `<C-x>` notation, or perhaps something else. The editing features are here to *improve* posts, not make it confirm to some style standard :-)

Related: [Should we use <kbd> in Markdown to indicate normal mode / insert mode keystrokes?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-use-kbd-in-markdown-to-indicate-normal-mode-insert-mode-keystrokes)

Comment: Yes, I find the `<C-x>` to be even cleaner (but that is IMH(umble)O). The Q arose as a result of this: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2350/220 (edit).

Comment: @Sukminder That's a good example of where at least fixing the `Alt k` part is appropriate, because I would assume that would mean "Press and release Alt, then press k" given that it uses a different style & the context of that post. As for the placement of the `+`, that seems like a [bikeshed](http://bikeshed.org/) to me ...

Comment: Yes, looking at it I'm leaning towards agreeing it being a bikeshed. Perhaps too much a whim to be worth a post, but here it was, and became.

Comment: What about <kbd><C-x></kbd>?

Comment: @Random832 You'd have to type `<kbd>&lt;C-x></kbd>` for it to work, but if that's the format that you prefer then go for it!